android.net.ConnectivityManager$TooManyRequestsException to sync data
Below is my ScoreSyncAPIWorker class to sync match scores to a server.
package com.xcelcorp.matchscoring.scoring.utils

import android.content.Context

import androidx.work.*

import com.xcelcorp.cricdost.app.SocketIOHandler

import com.xcelcorp.cricdost.repository.AppRepository

import com.xcelcorp.matchscoring.database.DbUtil

import com.xcelcorp.matchscoring.utils.AppBroadcasters

class ScoreSyncAPIWorker(var context: Context, params: WorkerParameters)
 : Worker(

    context, params) 
{

    var mTag = 
"ScoreWorker"

    private val repository by lazy  { AppRepository() }


    override fun doWork() : Result {
        // Do the work here--in this case, upload the images.
        //getting the input data
        val matchId = inputData.getString(TASK_MATCH_ID)
        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        val dbUtil = DbUtil(context)
        val unsyncedData = dbUtil.getUnsyncedData(matchId!!)
        return if (unsyncedData.size > 0) {
            val reqData = unsyncedData[0]
            // dbUtil.updateSyncProgress(reqData.getId(), "" + matchId, 1);
            val scoreId = reqData.id
            val mod = reqData.mod
            val actionType = reqData.actionType
            val subAction = reqData.subAction
            val lastBallId = reqData.getLastBallId()
            // val response = DataRepository.instance?.scoreSynApi(mod, actionType, subAction)
            val response = repository.scoreSynApi(mod, actionType, subAction)
            if (response != null) {
                val jsonResponse = response.body()
                var apiStatus = -1
                if (jsonResponse != null && jsonResponse.has("XSCStatus")) {
                    apiStatus = jsonResponse["XSCStatus"].asInt
                }
                if (apiStatus == 0) {
                    /*if (jsonResponse != null && jsonResponse.has("XSCData")) {
                        JsonObject xscData = jsonResponse.get("XSCData").getAsJsonObject();
                    }*/
                    dbUtil.updateSyncStatus(scoreId, "" + matchId, "" + jsonResponse, lastBallId)

                    //score update for other users
                    SocketIOHandler.scoreUpdated(matchId)
                    //score update for myself
                    ScoringHelper.onScoreUpdateSuccess(context, "" + matchId)

                    val isAllDataSync = dbUtil.getUnsyncedData(matchId).size == 0
                    AppBroadcasters.broadcastScoreSynced(applicationContext,
                        matchId.toInt(),
                        lastBallId,
                        isAllDataSync)

                    createWorkManager(context, matchId)
                } else {

                    var msg = ""
                    if (jsonResponse != null) {
                        msg = jsonResponse["XSCMessage"].asString
                    }
                    dbUtil.updateSyncProgress(scoreId, "" + matchId, 0)
                    if (msg.equals("You are not a scorer.", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        dbUtil.deleteMatchData(matchId.toString())
                    }
                }
                Result.success()
            } else {
                dbUtil.updateSyncProgress(scoreId, "" + matchId, 0)
                Result.success() //Result.failure(); //retry();
            }
        } else {
            Result.success()
        }
    }

    private fun createWorkManager(context: Context, matchId: String?) {
        val data = Data.Builder()
            .putString(TASK_MATCH_ID, matchId)
            .build()
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()
        val syncRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ScoreSyncAPIWorker::class.java)
            .setInputData(data)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .addTag("MATCH_$matchId")
            .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(syncRequest)
    }

    companion object {
        const val TASK_MATCH_ID = "task_match_id"
    }
}

the exception i got is
2024-11-25 12:12:37.420 29179-29263 AndroidRuntime          com.xcelcorp.cricdost                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: WM.task-3
                                                                                                    Process: com.xcelcorp.cricdost, PID: 29179
                                                                                                    android.net.ConnectivityManager$TooManyRequestsException
                                                                                                        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.convertServiceException(ConnectivityManager.java:3542)
                                                                                                        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:3730)
                                                                                                        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4222)
                                                                                                        at android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4189)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.utils.NetworkApi24.registerDefaultNetworkCallbackCompat(NetworkApi24.kt:26)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.constraints.trackers.NetworkStateTracker24.startTracking(NetworkStateTracker.kt:165)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.constraints.trackers.ConstraintTracker.addListener(ConstraintTracker.kt:52)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.constraints.controllers.BaseConstraintController$track$1.invokeSuspend(ContraintControllers.kt:62)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.constraints.controllers.BaseConstraintController$track$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.constraints.controllers.BaseConstraintController$track$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.ChannelFlowBuilder.collectTo$suspendImpl(Builders.kt:316)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.ChannelFlowBuilder.collectTo(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.CallbackFlowBuilder.collectTo(Builders.kt:330)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlow$collectToFun$1.invokeSuspend(ChannelFlow.kt:56)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
                                                                                                        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
                                                                                                        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@ebe8c59, androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl@bbb101e]
2024-11-25 12:12:37.444 29179-29179 chatty                  com.xcelcorp.cricdost                I  uid=10295(com.xcelcorp.cricdost) identical 4 lines Please give solution

I tried to handle exception using Result.retry().when the HTTP status code == 429,,additionally i added  Exponential backoff after 30 seconds.
